# File reading and writing in c#

Tags: c#, file

My Code is

```
        try
        {
            string mtellThemePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mtellThemePath"] == null ? Server.MapPath("~/App_Themes/") : ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mtellThemePath"].Contains("%%") ? Server.MapPath("~/App_Themes") : ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mtellThemePath"];

            string[] folderPaths = Directory.GetDirectories(mtellThemePath);
            string currentSurveyThemeName = hfSurveyName.Value + "_" + hfClientId.Value;
            string cloneSurveyThemeName = lstSurvey[0].SurveyName + "_" + Identity.Current.UserData.ClientId;
            string cloneSurveyThemePath = mtellThemePath + "\\" + lstSurvey[0].SurveyName + "_" + Identity.Current.UserData.ClientId;

            string cssFile = cloneSurveyThemePath + "\\" + cloneSurveyThemeName + ".css";
            string skinFile = cloneSurveyThemePath + "\\" + cloneSurveyThemeName + ".skin";

            string FileContentCSS = string.Empty;
            string FileContentSkin = string.Empty;

            foreach (string oFolder in folderPaths)
            {
                if (oFolder.Split('\\')[5] == currentSurveyThemeName)
                {
                    string[] cssSkinFiles = Directory.GetFiles(oFolder);
                    foreach (string objFile in cssSkinFiles)
                    {
                        if (objFile.Split('\\')[6].Split('.')[1] == "css")
                        {
                            FileContentCSS = File.ReadAllText(objFile);
                        }
                        if (objFile.Split('\\')[6].Split('.')[1] == "skin")
                        {
                            FileContentSkin = File.ReadAllText(objFile);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Directory.CreateDirectory(cloneSurveyThemePath);
            File.Create(cssFile);
            File.Create(skinFile);
            if (FileContentCSS != string.Empty)
            {
                File.WriteAllText(cssFile, FileContentCSS);
            }
            if (FileContentSkin != string.Empty)
            {
                File.WriteAllText(skinFile, FileContentSkin);
            }
            return lstSurvey[0].SurveyGuid;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

It is giving error as:

> The process cannot access the file
>   'D:\Projects\Mtelligence\Mtelligence.Web\App_Themes\Clone_ForCloneTest_-1\Clone_ForCloneTest_-1.css'
>   because it is being used by another process.

Please Help me ..........
how to solve this

Iam trying to read .css,.skin files from a folder and write those same files in another folder with different name

Comment: You will not get an answer if you do not explain as clearly as possible what you are attempting to do. By submitting source code and stating the error is assuming that other developers will understand what you are doing when in actual fact all they wil do is down-vote you. I have not down-voted you I am trying to give you some feedback in order that you will get to the root of your problem sooner.

Comment: Iam trying to read .css,.skin files from a folder and write those same files in another folder with different name

Comment: Do you have the file open in a text editor? The error message is pretty self explanatory, you need to give more info as to what the problem is (can't find what other program its in? Want to open it even if its in use? Its looking at the wrong file? YOu need to narrow things down a bit...

Comment: @user1309790: have you looked at just copying them? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look this:

```
File.Create(cssFile);
File.Create(skinFile);
if (FileContentCSS != string.Empty)
{
    File.WriteAllText(cssFile, FileContentCSS);
    // ...
}
```

Actually `File.Create` dos not just create a file but it creates the file and returns an open stream to it. Your subsequent call to `File.WriteAllText` will try to write a file open by yourself. In you case (because you do not use streams returned by `File.Create`) simply remove them:

```
if (FileContentCSS != string.Empty)
{
    File.WriteAllText(cssFile, FileContentCSS);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From the error you are getting I imagine that you are not closing a stream to the file you are manipulating. Possibly the lines:

> ```
> > File.Create(cssFile);
> > File.Create(skinFile);
> ```

They return a FileStream object that you should probably flush and close when you are finished with it.

Remember it is rude not to flush :)

So do this for your Creating your files:

```
using (var stream = File.Create(cssFile))
{
    // do your tasks here
    stream.Flush();
}
```

Comment: I don't think File.Create is required in this case, but try using a using statement instead of stream.Close(); It will protect against exceptions.

Comment: Yeah the using statement is better; I think Adriano has answered the question more specifically to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason you're not using `File.Copy` ?

```
    // To copy a file to another location and 
    // overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
```