# The process cannot access the file 'R:\mft classes\c# fundamental\c#.net apps\employee info\fileList.txt' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#

i'm trying to write some file names in the "fileList.txt".the file has been created but when i try to write in it , it shows me the error above. what should i do?

```
string strFilePath;
//the current path is : "R:\mft classes\c# fundamental\c#.net apps\employeeinfo\WindowsFormsApplication2\bin\Debug"

strFilePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
strFilePath = Directory.GetParent(strFilePath).ToString();
strFilePath = Directory.GetParent(strFilePath).ToString();
strFilePath = Directory.GetParent(strFilePath).ToString();
strFilePath = strFilePath + "\\fileList.txt";
File.Create(strFilePath);
foreach (string saveMe in listBox1.Items)
{
File.WriteAllText(strFilePath, saveMe);
}
```

Comment: Close the `fileList.txt` before you run your program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [File reading and writing in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362267/file-reading-and-writing-in-c-sharp) (exactly same error). BTW WriteAllText won't append.

Comment: Code tip: instead of `strFilePath + "\\fileList.txt"` use `Path.Combine()`.

Comment: The call to `File.Create` creates the file _and opens it_.  That call is not necessary.   The `File.WriteAllText` method will create the file if it doesn't exist.  However, it will also overwrite the file each time.

Answer (score 1):

Use stream writer instead.

```
string strFilePath;
//the current path is : "R:\mft classes\c# fundamental\c#.net apps\employeeinfo\WindowsFormsApplication2\bin\Debug"

strFilePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
strFilePath = strFilePath + "\\fileList.txt";

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, true))
{
    foreach (string saveMe in listBox1.Items)
    {
        sw.Write(saveMe);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Problem is exactly what the error says. If you have the file opened in any other program, for example text editor, like Notepad or Word, close it before running your code.

Comment: It's his own code keeping the file open. Also, Notepad doesn't keep files open like that.